# Can't change a project's Default Namespace in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution that includes various C# projects, and I just now noticed that I can't change the default namespace on any of them.

When I go to Properties --> Application on any of the project and change the "Default Namespace" field, a fatal error dialog pops up that says:

```
exception of type 'system.runtime.interopservices.externalexception' was thrown
```

At this point Visual Studio becomes unusable, as I can't close it or leave the screen, every click or button combination I press makes the same dialog pop up. The only thing I can do is terminate VS with the task manager.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan : did that work for you, or are you just spitballing? Would like to avoid it if possible, but if no other solutions pop up   I'll try, thanks.

Comment: I never have that kind of problems. Let me know when you will reinstall VS.

Comment: I have the same problem using VS 2012 Premium with Update 4 and with VS 2013 Professional with Update 1. I've created a bug for this with MS at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/828822/cant-change-default-namespace-in-visual-studio-2013-csharp-project.

Comment: It works for me, but it takes quite a few minutes for VS to change namespaces in all relevant files such as those in service references.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got around it by just renaming the `<RootNamespace>` node in the `.csproj` file

Comment: Had forgotten about this question, but that's what I did myself after I didn't find any fix, I can confirm it works. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try to do this in another way:

Ctrl-H - Find: PreviousNameSpaceName Replace: NewNamespaceName

You can also right click the namespace in code and Refactor->Rename.

What is more: you can change the names of your projects, solutions, directories - etc. Namespaces, when adding new files, are generated using these names in fact.

Comment: Yeah well, that's a workaround, but I wondered if there's a proper solution. Right now every time I create a new class I will have to change the namespace manually if I can't change the default one. It's not critical, but it's annoying to be honest

Comment: @Master_T The Default Namespace nothing deal with actual namespaces in your solution. It is just says VS to use this namespace on code generation.

Comment: Do you use VS2013 or VS2013 Update 1? Is there any more error information or only the piece that you pasted in your question?

Comment: It downloaded Update 1 a few days ago. I must admit I don't know if it worked before update 1. That might be it tho... And no, no other errors come up.

Comment: I have updated my answer - see above: changing Default Namespace might not be really needed to achieve what you want

Comment: For this particular solution I need the project/exe name to be different from the namespace, for internal structure reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had to investigate the issue in our company and I found another workaround in our case. So I think it make sense to add it here.

**Possible Solution**

Check if you have more than one suo-File for the project/solution and delete the one which doesn't has the ".v12.suo" naming (better delete both)

**Story behind:**

We still have two Visual Studio installed (2010 and 2013) and some of our developer worked recently on 2010. So they had on the file system a regular ".suo"-File. Afterwards (some weeks later) they started to use 2013 (which created a ".v12.suo"-File).

We renamed both suo files, started VS2013 (which created the v12.suo) and were able to rename the namespace without a crash. In addition we had this issue not on all solutions. I didn't see yet a pattern, but in our case it happened mostly on solution with at least two projects and referenced project-libraries.